# Any Idea of algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

I'm a Computer Science guy, I'm given an assessment exercise, but I realize it does involve math, an algorithm.

So the condition :
`John is a young boy who likes numbers. He thinks the digits in the numbers aren't ordered as they might. For a number to have ordered digits, he writes the number (for example 42) and then this John somehow picks a number (for example 29) from whose digits will be added (2 + 9) and will generate another number - 11, and so on (1+1) till you generate the next number - 2.
Finally 42 = 29 + 11 + 2`.

I can't understand how John picks the first number to generate the next exact numbers and to be the sum. There must be some algorithm.

**In Short:** Given a number like 42, I have to find whether there exists another number (in this case 29) where taking the "sum sequence of the digits", gives the first number.

**Restrictions:** 10 <= John's Number <= 100000. I mean I don't want to loop from 10 to 100000 and check every number (as someone said in the comments) - that's not efficient.

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, can't understand the question at all.  Which is the "first number"?  is there a second number?  What is a "sum sequence"?

Comment: I edited it so that it makes a bit more sense. But it's still confusing. Do you mean, "Establish whether there exists some $x$ for which the number equals the "sum sequence" of the digits of $x$"?

Comment: Look, I'm a Computer Science guy... I don't know how to explain it in Math terms. I want to solve an assesment, and looking for an algorithm.
Okay, I'll edit my Question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're given a number like $42$, and you have to find whether there exists another number (in this case $29$) where taking the "sum sequence of the digits", as you put it, gives the first number. Right?

Comment: @Théophile Yes. Do you know anything about it? I edited my question.

Comment: nice question finally ; I'm trying ...

Comment: The sequence is uniquely determined by the first number you choose, so if you are supposed to find an algorithm to do it you can (albeit in a stupid way) try every number from $1$ to $n$ and check if the condition is true.

Comment: How do I choose the first number, that's the question.
And the gotcha is that the John's number range is : 10 <= Number <= 100000

Comment: You can easily try all of them within seconds on a computer with that range. The interesting question is if there is a mathematical way of determining if it is possible or not.

Comment: That's not efficient, and that's easy. That's why I've asked here.

Comment: **Hint:** I don't know if there's a way to tell immediately, but at least you can narrow the search considerably. Notice that if a generating number $x$ has $n$ digits, then the sum of its digits is no more than $9n$.

Comment: Let's say `x` = 42 ; `n`=2; and `sum of digits <= 9n`=18 ; 

In This example the sum of the digits is equal to `2+9(29) + 1+1(11) + 2` = 15 ?

Comment: @Théophile: it's that I'm trying. The strongest bound comes quickly and the search is limited. I'm trying another hints to narrow better

Comment: Have your tried to do a reverse search: Lets say $a_0=42$ is the number you want to consider as sum. You pick a number $x_1$ from 1 to 9, now you you consider $a_1:=42-x_1$ and as $x_2<=a_1$ a number, which digit sum is $x_1$. For arbitrary step $i$ you get $x_i<=a_{i-1}$ with sum of digits ($x_i$)=$x_{i-1}$. This might be a little bit faster than from top to bottom (if you have a proper algorithm which pops out all numbers with a specified digit sum)

Comment: A straightforward search will be very fast provided you avoid repeated computations. Say $n$ is Jonh's number, create an array `a = range(n)`, and browse numbers from $10$ to $n-1$ doing `a[i] += a[sum_of_digits(i)]` and then checking if `a[i] == n` (in which case $i$ is a solution and you can stop).

Comment: Not sure that the question is unclear ... However I prefer the first and short  version of the question

Comment: Does it say which numbers can John see this way. I mean what will he do for 12? It can't be 6 +6.

Comment: No, it can't! Because if you have a number with one digit you can't add anymore..

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment, but it actually can help solve it much more quickly.

Edit: The Maximum Difference I describe here is the maximum difference possible between a number (e.g. 42) and a number whose digits added together repeatedly will equal the first number (e.g. 29, 2+9 = 11, 1 + 1 = 2, 29 + 11 + 2 = 42) This is only a helpful trick that could be used to find these numbers by hand without trying every number below it. It is not an algorithm for solving the OPs problem.

Say you start with a number 5376. 5376 has 4 digits, so the maximum difference between 5376 and a possible picked number is 5 (4+1) * 9 = 45

Meaning that if a number (or numbers) exists, it will be between 5375 (5376-1) and 5331 (5376-45) (inclusive)
In addition, the difference seems to only fall on certain numbers within these ranges. Specifically, the difference never falls on
10,12,14,16,18,20,29,31,38,40,47,49,53 (at least within the 100000)

For our example, this means that it cannot be 5366(5376-10), 5364(5376-12), 5362(5376-14)... etc.

For our example, there is only one selected number for 5376. It's 5353(5376-23).

While this doesn't solve it outright, this does reduce it to a number of possibilities for any given number to a set that can be tested by hand or possibly even in your head if you're good enough.

Source: Experimentation

Edit: I should probably add this to my answer to clarify.

The maximum difference for 2 digits is 21 (e.g. 78->99)

The maximum difference for 3 digits is 34 (e.g. 899->933)

The maximum difference for 4 digits is 43 (e.g. 9899->9942)

The maximum difference for 5 digits is 54 (e.g. 99939->99993)

The maximum difference for 6 digits is 66 (e.g. 999895->999961)

The maximum difference for 7 digits is 78 (e.g. 9999896->9999974)

The maximum difference for 8 digits is 90 (e.g. 99999897->99999987)

We can see from numbers outside the given set that the rule no longer holds, but for the given set, it's still something John could memorize as a numerical trick that would allow him to solve them in his head. This only works because (5+1)*9 = 54 >= 54, (4+1)*9 = 45 >= 43, (3+1)*9 = 36 >= 34, and (2+1)*9 = 27 >= 21. You could just as easily use 5*11 + 1 = 56 >= 54, 4*11 + 1 = 45 >= 43, 3*11 + 1 = 34 > = 34, 2*11 + 1 = 23 >=21

Comment: How did you find out the difference is 45? I mean, why 5 * 9 ? Where did you take these (5 and 9)?

Comment: It's actually just a trick that I know works for the given set.
The maximum difference for 2 digits is 21
The maximum difference for 3 digits is 34
The maximum difference for 4 digits is 43
The maximum difference for 5 digits is 54
The maximum difference for 6 digits is 66
The maximum difference for 7 digits is 78
As you can see, the rule doesn't hold for numbers outside your set, however given that there was a set restriction, I figured it would be simple enough for a kid like john to memorize some numerical tricks that held for the numbers he was interested in.

Comment: ummm... I can't realize where does the maximum difference come from?
May be : 2 digits = 18, 3 digits = 27, 4 digits = 36, 5 digits = 45, 6 digits = 54 ?

Have you misspelled the difference for 5 digits? 54 or 45 ?

Comment: By maximum difference, I mean the maximum difference possible between a number (e.g. 42) and it's number whose digits added equals it (e.g. 29). For example 90 = 69+(6+9)+(6). 90-69 = 21 You won't find a greater maximum difference possible in the two digits, but since the maximum difference possible is always lower than the (number of digits + 1) * 9 you can use that as a mental trick to reduce the problem size (within the parameters given) If you want to change the mental trick multiplying the number of digits by 11 and adding 1 seems to work pretty well too. 3*11+1 = 34, 2*11+1=23

Comment: You must have said so from the beginning, Edit your POST! 
you said that 2 digits = 21, 4 = 43.